# Displaying a Gridview and ViewPager in the same layout

Tags: android, gridview, layout, android-framelayout

I would like to display on the same page a viewpager and a gridview  like this one ![What I would like :)][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xzg7T.jpg  but what i get is that ![what I got][1]
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZxwU.png .
There are my layouts.**The Gridview Item**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/frag_Acc_gridView_imageView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#215487" 
     android:scaleType="centerCrop"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_logo"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/frag_Acc_gridview_textView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/frag_Acc_gridView_imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="#80000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**GridView layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_acc_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
</GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**the main layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="10"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_acc_viewpager"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:layout_weight="6">
</FrameLayout>

 <FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_accueil_gridview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px" 
    android:layout_weight="4"
    >
</FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look of this. You will get some help:-

http://www.rogcg.com/blog/2013/10/20/working-with-fragments-and-viewpager-on-android

Comment: thanks for your answer but, I resolved it using tablelayout and I obtained the result without changing to many things in my layout. it seems thats the gridview is but default scrollable so, it doesn't fit in my case.